# Travis-ci can't find boost/geometry.hpp

Tags: travis-ci, boost-geometry

In .travis.yml I have:

```
dist: precise

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      # For gcc >= 4.8
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
      # For cmake >= 2.8.8 (for CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
      - kubuntu-backports
      - boost-latest
    packages:
      - g++-4.8
      - cmake
      - libboost-thread-dev
      - libboost-graph-dev
      - libcgal-dev
      - postgresql-server-dev-all
      - postgresql-common
```

In CmakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Boost)
if(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  message(STATUS "Boost headers were found here: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  find_file(MYVAR geometry.hpp)
  message(STATUS "geometry.hpp  found here: ${MYVAR}")
endif(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

When I run the cmake in my computer I get:

```
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Boost headers were found here: /usr/include
-- geometry.hpp  found here: /usr/include/boost/geometry.hpp
```

But when working in github's travis it can not find geometry.hpp:

```
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Boost headers were found here: /usr/include
-- geometry.hpp  found here: MYVAR-NOTFOUND
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
```

Something I am missing in the addons section that its not finding the header only library geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Geometry was added to Boost in version 1.47 (in 2011 IIRC)

Therefore, using 1.46.1, it cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, very much.